# formatear fecha con date_format

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY fecha DESC";
                      $data = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
                        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        $articulos_query = "SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria WHERE id = " . $r['id_categoria'];
                        $articulos = mysqli_query($cnx, $articulos_query);
                        echo "<h3>" . $r['titulo'] . "</h3>
                              <h4>".$r['descripcion']."</h4>
                              <p>".$r['contenido']."</p>
                              <hr>
                              <p>Autor: ".$r['subido']." &nbsp;|&nbsp; Categoria: ";
                        while ($art = mysqli_fetch_array($articulos)) {
                           echo $art['categoria'];
                        };
                        echo" &nbsp;|&nbsp Subido el dia: ".$r[DATE_format('fecha', "%d/%m/%Y")]."</p>
                        <hr>";
                      };
                    ?>
```

lo que quiero hacer es que me ponga la fecha con el estilo 00/00/000, pero en vez de eso solo me pne un digito del 1 al 4
que estare haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la manera como pasas los parametros cuando vas a formatear la fecha

```php
$r[DATE_format('fecha', "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

Prueba cambiandolo a

```php
DATE_format($r['fecha'], "d/m/Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba crear un objeto de tipo DateTime, y pásale como parámetro el string de la fecha.
Luego, aplica el filtro de formato:

```
<?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY fecha DESC";
                      $data = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
                        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                        $articulos_query = "SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria WHERE id = " . $r['id_categoria'];
                        $articulos = mysqli_query($cnx, $articulos_query);
                        echo "<h3>" . $r['titulo'] . "</h3>
                              <h4>".$r['descripcion']."</h4>
                              <p>".$r['contenido']."</p>
                              <hr>
                              <p>Autor: ".$r['subido']." &nbsp;|&nbsp; Categoria: ";
                        while ($art = mysqli_fetch_array($articulos)) {
                           echo $art['categoria'];
                        };
                        $date = new DateTime('fecha'); //Coloca la fecha que desees

                        echo" &nbsp;|&nbsp Subido el dia: ".$r[$date->format('d/m/Y')]."</p>
                        <hr>";
                      };
                    ?>
```